The classification of finitely generated modules over the ring of (Laurent polynomials in multiple variables)
Let  $M=\mathbb Z [x_1^{\pm1},\dots,x_n^{\pm1}]$ be the ring of Laurent polynomials in multiple variables. May I ask if there are known results that give the classification/nice description of the finitely generated modules over the $M$? In the case when $n=1$, i.e. when we have a single variable, a nice description can be found in a paper by Daniel S. Silver and Susan G. Williams, which contains the following theorem:

We denote the ring $\mathbb{Z}\left[t, t^{-1}\right]$ of Laurent
polynomials by $\Lambda$. It is a Noetherian unique factorization
domain.
Proposition 2.4. Assume that $M$ is a finitely generated
$\Lambda$-module.
There exists a pair $U, B$ of finitely generated abelian groups and monomorphisms $f, g: U \rightarrow B$ such that $M$ is isomorphic to
the infinite free product $$\cdots \oplus_U B \oplus_U B \oplus_U
 \cdots$$
with identical amalgamations $B \stackrel{g}{\leftarrow} U
 \xrightarrow{f} B$;

May I ask if there is any known work that can generalise this result to the multivariable case? Any reference would be really appreciated.

crossposted to overflow https://mathoverflow.net/q/484686/479955
